# How to read the last array line in text file in Fortran 77 and save it in an array?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

For example, I have a write command to save an array with 6 fields in a text file like this:

```
 OPEN(UNIT=26,FILE='W:\Partikeltemperaturfeld.txt',
&FORM ='FORMATTED',STATUS='UNKNOWN',
&ACTION='READWRITE')   
C 
WRITE (26,FMT='(6(F8.3,3X))') TFIELD(1,1:6)
C
REWIND(26)
```

Now I want to read and save the 6 values of the last line of my text file in another array with 6 fields like:

```
IOS = 0
DO WHILE (IOS.EQ.0)
READ(UNIT=26,FMT='(6(F8.3,3X))',IOSTAT=IOS) TEST(1:6)
END DO
```

This could be the content of the last line in my file:

```
1377.445   1373.171   1363.639   1352.062   1341.476   1334.764
```

The aim is to save the last line in existing format.

But after doing this I always get values `0.000000E+00`. How can I read and save the last line of my 'W:\Partikeltemperaturfeld.txt' file in array `TEST(1:6)`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The line should be READ(UNIT=26,FMT='(6(F8.3,3X))',IOSTAT=IOS) TEST(1:6). But i always get values of 0.000000E+00. How would you save the last line of my 'W:\Partikeltemperaturfeld.txt' in an array?

Comment: How does the file look like? Show it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
DO WHILE (IOS.EQ.0)
  READ(UNIT=26,FMT='(6(F8.3,3X))',IOSTAT=IOS) TEST(1:6)
END DO
```

the loop will exit when there was some problem (end of file or an error condition) reading the array in the input list. The value of the variable being read is than undefined. You cannot use it. It can contain *anything*.

BTW your code is *not* Fortran 77 conforming (it is Fortran 90 or later) so I will not try to make my suggestion 100% Fortran 77 either. You can do

```
DO
  READ(UNIT=26,FMT='(6(F8.3,3X))',IOSTAT=IOS) TMP
  IF (IOS.EQ.0) THEN
    TEST = TMP
  ELSE
    EXIT
  END DO
END DO
```

where `TEST` and `TMP` are arrays of size 6